# Android: onListItemClick not opening up the .xml file

Tags: android, listview, listitem

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        if(position == 0){
            setContentView(R.layout.cuisine);
        }
    }

I have an array of Strings and i'm using the above method to try and open up a new xml file called 'cuisine' when it is clicked. but it keeps failing!

Have I done this right, or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Ok from looking at similar problems on the web, people have said to get the onListItemClick() to start a new activity and using that new activity to then open up the new view?

So what i've done is this...

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Intent dundrumIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DundrumSelector.class);
    dundrumIntent.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivityForResult(dundrumIntent, 0);
}
```

and then

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

import android.os.Bundle;

public class DundrumSelector extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

    if(position == 0){
        setContentView(R.layout.cuisine);
    }
}
```

}

Yet i'm still getting the same problem. The program crashes when I click on an item in the listView. And yes i've added the activity to the manifest.

Does anyone have a resolution to this as alot of people seem to be having the same problem.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Please find what exception caused the program to crash using adb logcat and let us know

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got it working.

I had changed the avd back to an original avd that i had set it up with and it seems to work ok now.

For some reason it didn't work when i had it on the google avd?

Comment: Perhaps they have different API versions? It is very difficult to tell what the problem is without knowing what exception occured

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included a call to super in `onListItemClick`

Try making the first line: `super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);`